# OpenLayers android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, openlayers, marker

I'm currently working on a map/navigational project for Android, and I chose OpenLayers because it claimed to support mobile development and the examples worked well on my Android phone.

I made a basic map prototype with one marker, a popup from the marker, and a layer switch control. All of this works as intended on both my PC and my Android, except for one weird issue with Android. I'm the .html file and all dependencies through a WebView in my app, and there are some weird issues coming up. For one, whenever I tap something like my marker or the zoom controller, an orange box appears briefly around it, and sometimes it doesn't register the tap.

To clarify, I have touch navigation enabled on my map, and all events for the popups are on-touch and working for the most part. But the orange boxes and occasional failure to register a tap are really ruining any degree of polish that the app has. Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this at before, and possibly has a fix?

Answer (score 0):

whenever i see this type of behavior, i.e. orange crisscrossed boxes in openlayers, it is many times caused by failure to locate icon graphics files.  try creating a marker whose icon file does not exist where it should and see if that is the "orange box" that you describe.

if so, then you should check any broken links (mouseovers, especially).